# PHP mkdir() permission denied

Tags: permissions, php, apache-http-server, ownership

I've got a server setup with Centos 5.6, Apache 2.2.19 and PHP 5.2.17. PHP is being handled by suPHP.

In the global php.ini
`safe_mode = off`
`open_basedir = none`

Apache is set to run as `nobody` in the suPHP config.

I've got two domains setup in:
`/home/user1/public_html` and `/home/user2/public_html`

Both `public_html` directories have permissions of 0750 with group as `nobody`

All files/directories in each user directory are owned by that user and have the group set to that user as well.

I'm running a script in `/home/user1/public_html/scripts/functions.php` which is trying to create a directory in `/home/user2/public_html/user_files` (which has chmod permissions set to 0757), however I'm getting a permission denied error...

I'm assuming this is to do with the fact that PHP is being run as `nobody`, but I'm not sure what to change to enable scripts in each user's folder to write into the other user's folder, unless I make the user folder's writable by anybody, which doesn't sound very safe...

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

EDIT:

```
drwx--x--x    root.root      /home  
drwx-wx--x    user2.user2    /home/user2
drwxrwx---    user2.nobody   /home/user2/public_html 
drwxrwxrwx    user2.nobody   /home/user2/public_html/user_files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new group containing user1 and user2 and just changed the group ownerships on the relevant folders to allow cross-folder writing.

Answer (score 1):

The directory `/home/user2/public_html/user_files` is owned by `xxx:nobody` and comes with the permissions `757`, correct?
`757` means it is read/accessible by anyone, but write access is only granted to users not in group `nobody`. So your problem might be solved if you just change the group of this directory, or better, change the permissions to `775`. With `775` the owner and the group have write permissions, so they can create further files/directories in it, but no one else is able to write to this dir.

Comment: I'll add the full permissions above.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on F15, and SELinux was the culprit in my case. Try:

```
chcon -R -h -t http_sys_rw_content_t /home/user2/public_html/user_files
```

Use the same command on any other dirs where you want Apache to have R/W access. If it works, use semanage to make the context change permanent across reboots.

Comment: The server has cPanel and WHM installed - do you know if I would need to change anything in cPanel/WHM in addition to this?

Comment: Additionally, SELinux is disabled...